# compile-time array initialization with non-const variable size

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I having a confusion about what is going on *behind the scene* of array initialization.

```
int n= 3;
int a[n]; // compile succeeds
```

but,

```
int n = 3;
int a[n] = {1, 2, 3};   // compile error
```

error message from *codeblock*:

```
error: variable-sized object 'a' may not be initialized
```

My understanding is:
first snippet, n elements are allocated but uninitialized. Second one allocates n elements and initializes them to `{1, 2, 3}`. Both do almost the same thing, but why second one causes error.

---

Please clarify my understanding or leave me some resources (I've tried, but couldn't find the close answer).

---

compiler: **mingw32-g++**

Comment: What is the error?  What compiler are you using? `int a[n];` is not standard and should not compile.

Comment: VLAs are not standard although GCC supports them siltently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C99, it's explicitly forbidden by the standard (6.7.8p3)

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or an object type that is not a variable length array type.

Even though we can see that `n` is a constant value, it is not marked as such.

AFAIK, C++ standard does not allow for variable-length arrays (i.e. `n` not being `const` or `constexpr`) although most compilers support it following C rules.